# Find out what values of `array1` are missing in `array2`

Tags: arrays, bash, comparison

```
declare -a array1=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 )
declare -a array2=( 1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 )
```

In bash, how can I get a third array of the values that are present in `array1` but absent in `array2`? In the above example, the expected output is `( 4 8 )`

Comment: @andlrc. Thanks. I don't quite understand what a command substitution is (but will investigate the question). I have changed the first to correctly define an array.

Comment: @Remi.b Any reason you are doing this? This isn't really what shell scripting is for.  Of cause it's possible, but do you have a specific goal in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `mapfile`, `comm`, `sort` and process substitution:

```
array1=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 )
array2=( 1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 )
mapfile -t arr < <(comm -23 --nocheck-order \
                       <(printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}" | sort -n) \
                       <(printf "%s\n" "${array2[@]}" | sort -n))
```

Result:

```
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="4" [1]="8")'
```

Explanation, from the inside out:

- Print the array one element per line and sort:

  ```
  $ printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}" | sort -n
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
  10
  11
  12
  ```

  and the same for `array2`.
- Wrap these pipes into process substitutions and use them as arguments for `comm`:

  ```
  comm -23 --nocheck-order \
      <(printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}" | sort -n) \
      <(printf "%s\n" "${array2[@]}" | sort -n)
  ```

  The `-23` reduces the result to values unique to the first array; `--nocheck-order` suppresses a warning about the input not being lexicographically sorted. The output of this is

  ```
  4
  8
  ```
- Read each line into an array element with `mapfile` (`-t` removes the newlines):

  ```
  mapfile -t arr < <(comm -23 --nocheck-order \
                     <(printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}" | sort -n) \
                     <(printf "%s\n" "${array2[@]}" | sort -n))
  ```

  Now, `arr` contains the two values as shown above.

The `sort` step is not strictly required, but makes the solution work for non-sorted arrays as well.

Comment: You could use `printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}"` instead of the IFS+echo construct.  In this example, using `"${array1[@]}"` instead of `"${array1[*]}"` matters with the `printf` variant; using `*` you get a single string passed as an argument to `printf`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's indeed more elegant. `"${array1[*]}"` instead of `"${array1[@]}"` matters also in my variant, by the way, as otherwise `IFS` isn't used to separate the array elements - just a space.

Answer (score 1):

Following onliner will do the trick :

```
diff -y <(printf '%s\n' "${array2[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${array1[@]}") | grep -Po '[\|\<\>][\t]\K[0-9]+$'
```

The `printf` is used to print elements in separate lines. Now the `diff -y` gives the output :

```
1           1    
2           2
3           3
5         | 4
6           5
7           6   
9           7
10        | 8
11          9
12          10
            11
            12
```

Now all you have to filter the numbers after the `|`(or sometimes`<` or `>`). I used `grep` for this, but `sed` can be used too. If your array is not sorted, simply add sort to each `printf` like this :

```
(printf '%s\n' "${arrayN[@]}"|sort -n)
```